# If a function $f: \left [ a,b \right ] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies some form of continuity, then $f ([a,b])$ has Lebesgue measure of zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f: \left [ a,b \right ] \to \mathbb{R}^2$. And suppose that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x_1, x_2\in \left [ a,b \right ]: \left|x_1 -x_2\right| < \delta \Rightarrow \left \|f(x_1) -f(x_2)\right \|<\varepsilon \left|x_1 -x_2\right|$.
>
> Show that $f \left ( \left [ a,b \right ] \right )$ is of Lebesgue measure zero.

They call this form of continuity "Equicontinuity", but I have never heard this term used for a single function, only for a family of functions.

Me and a friend tried this for some time and couldn't solve it. It probably involves finding a rectangular cover of $f \left ( \left [ a,b \right ] \right )$, but I don't know enough properties of this "Equicontinuity" nor do I have enough intuition to work with it. My friend says he didn't even find non-constant functions that satisfy it. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$? The title and question do not match.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$. fixed.

Comment: Hmm, good question, intuitively this continuity condition will imply that the image is at most 'one-dimensional', by that I mean something that looks like a curve, which obviously has zero measure as it has no area. But I need to think about the details of showing that.

Comment: Are you sure the absolute value behind the epsilon belongs there?

Comment: @Mathematician42 curves have zero measure area is false. Example is given by the pathological [Osgood curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) which have positive area. They are not uniformly continuous though.

Comment: @G.S. I am aware of that, but I suspect all these 'space-filling' curves are not equicontinuous. As shown in the answer below, this condition is quite restrictive. But you are right, my comment is perhaps misleading.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to call it "uniform continuity".  I would use "equicontinuity" in describing a whole family of functions where the $\epsilon$ chosen for each $\delta$ may be chosen to work for all functions in the family.

Comment: I must say they didn't exactly call it Equicontinuity. The original problem was stated in Hebrew, where they called it by the same name Equicontinuity is called in Hebrew.

Comment: If you ask $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$ (without the additional factor $|x_1-x|$), *that's* the definition of uniform continuity, which however is not sufficient for the statement to hold (there are continuous plane-filling curves, and every continuous function from a compact is uniformly continuous). Moreover the role of $\delta$ is useless, because if the assumption is true for one $\delta$, by triangle inequality it's true for every $\delta$. If instead you just require that there's one fixed $\epsilon$ you obtain Lipschitz-continuity, under which the statement is true and a nice exercise.

Comment: I did ask for $\left \| f(x_1) - f(x_2) \right \| < \varepsilon \left | x_1 - x_2 \right |$. Also, if I am a measure theory student it's safe to assume I know what a uniformly continuous function is.

Comment: @Bary12 I didn't want to address you specifically, I was just clarifying because the term had been cited in the comments above. In any case what I'm saying is that this is quite a strange definition of equicontinuity (or whatever continuity) because it implies $f$ is constant! And then the exercise becomes not at all about measure theory, so it seems strange that they ask to show it has measure zero, while in fact it is a point.  Instead if you ask just for Lipschitz continuity you obtain a nice exercise which has some measure theory in it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f=(f_1,f_2)$ . Show that the $ \epsilon - \delta$ - property gives that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable and $f_1'=f_2'=0$ on $[a,b]$.

Hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: Nice one, didn't realize that! Clearly equicontinuity is quite a strong condition.

Comment: Wow, very nice!! (+1)